Failing to authenticate Microsoft Graph Java/Kotlin Client correctly
I have a bash script that uses curl and the microsoft graph api to get what I want. But I fail to translate this script into Kotlin code with the MS Java Graph Api SDK.
The working script is:
export CLIENT_ID='XXX' 
export CLIENT_SECRET='XXX' 
export TENANT_ID='XXX'
exoprt SCOPE='api://ourApp/2023/CustomScope'
export TOKEN=`curl \
    -d grant_type=client_credentials \
    -d client_id=$CLIENT_ID \
    -d client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET \
    -d scope=$SCOPE \
    -d resource=https://graph.microsoft.com \
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID/oauth2/token \
    | jq -j .access_token`
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/XXX/appRoleAssignedTo \
    | jq .

I get a list of role assignments to my app. (The api with correct permissions is exposed under that scope)
Now I'm trying to recreate this in Kotlin using the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#client-credentials-provider
val clientSecretCredential = ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(appId)
    .clientSecret(secret)
    .tenantId(tenantId)
    .build()

client = GraphServiceClient(
    clientSecretCredential,
    "api://ourApp/2023/CustomScope"
)

val result = client.servicePrincipals().byServicePrincipalId(appObjectId).get().appRoleAssignedTo

If I fire the request with this client I get the error
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope api://drupalwiki/2023/SyncEverything openid profile offline_access is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI)

If I use "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as a scope, I only get an empty list. I also cannot rename our scope to e.g "api://ourApp/2023/.default" in the end because the Azure UI says this name is invalid. Apart from that, since the bash script workds, I would just like to initialize the client in the same way, is that possible?
Chees and thanks!

That's because appRoleAssignedTo is not a property, but a relationship, so you need to request for appRoleAssignedTo like this
val result = client.servicePrincipals().byServicePrincipalId(appObjectId).appRoleAssignedTo().get();

The scope must be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Hey thanks for the answer, appRoleAssignesTo is of type " java. util. List<com. microsoft. graph. models. AppRoleAssignment> getAppRoleAssignedTo()". There is no further get. It is a getter not a property. Kotlin just accesses getters generally as properties.

@Tom my mistake, it should be val result = client.servicePrincipals().byServicePrincipalId(appObjectId).appRoleAssignedTo().get(); without get() in the middle

Ah thanks that works. Holy Moly,... could've searched for that for ages since the upper one also compiles but fetches too early. It is definitly weird though, that in the script I need to use our custom scope and with the sdk I need to use the default scope.
